# How to sort by numbers in alpha numeric string?

Tags: regex, perl, sorting

If I have an array of strings with the following format:

```
[1900] ABC 15
```

How can I sort the array using perl `sort` so that it sorts by the first number, then by the second?

This example from [perldoc sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) seems to be relevant:

```
my @new = sort {
    ($b =~ /=(\d+)/)[0] <=> ($a =~ /=(\d+)/)[0]
                        ||
                fc($a)  cmp  fc($b)
} @old;
```

Comment: When you say Perl, you should show some code in context. This `[1900] ABC 15` means nothing.

Comment: I would think you will need to define your own sorting subroutine then examine the parts of the string inside you want to compare. You could possibly append the second number to the first to get one number (190015) for the comparison.

Comment: @sin That `=` is just from a pattern in the example, quoted from the docs.  Note that one does need to take the element `(...)[0]` since otherwise the `<=>` would be comparing two _lists_ (even if with a single element each), and since it  imposes the scalar context  we'd have the comparison of numbers of elements in each, `1 <=> 1`.

Comment: @zdim - Ah, I remember. You have to make the regex respond to wantarray to get a list, and of course I don't think <=> expects list context, therefore the index. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Remember, as the docs say, this is hugely inefficient.

Answer (score 5):

The example pulled from docs shows the idea: Compare by one criterion and if they are found equal by the `cmp` or `<=>` [equality operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators), which then return `0`, go to the next criterion.

So in this case compare by the first number in the string, then by the second.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @old = ('[1900] ABC 15', '[1900] ABC 5', '[1800] ABC 20'); 

my @new = sort { 
    my ($a1, $a2) = $a =~ /([0-9]+)/g;
    my ($b1, $b2) = $b =~ /([0-9]+)/g;

    $a1 <=> $b1  or $a2 <=> $b2;

} @old;

say for @new;
```

prints

```
[1800] ABC 20
[1900] ABC 5
[1900] ABC 15
```

If the sort needs to be in the descending order swap `a` and `b` in comparisons.

This can be done more efficiently, in the first place by pre-computing the regexes for the whole list so that they aren't re-done every time an element is compared. The continuation of the example from docs shows this, the last version being the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

But recall that such optimizations are demonstrable only for larger data sets, and that for simple calculations their overhead counts, too.
The above basic `sort` generally suffices.

---

Having discussed the problem "*using perl `sort`*", as asked for, I'd like to add that there are also modules written precisely for this purpose, "natural sorting," as they call it.

An example with [Sort::Key::Natural](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Sort::Key::Natural qw(natsort);

my @strings = qw(
    19_b_2
    13_z_7
    13_b_7
    20_a_1 
    13_b_5 
);

say for natsort @strings;
```

Prints

```
13_b_5
13_b_7
13_z_7
19_b_2
20_a_1
```

This sorts on numerical parts first, and then alphabetically. That second sort wasn't asked for and the `sort` above doesn't do it. But that manual sort can easily be amended with criterion while the nice module of course can't be as flexible (can't drop the alphabetical sort).

---

**Note**   A `[0-9]` is matched by `\d` but so are other characters (360 more I'm told), it being Unicode aware. This isn't the case with `/a` *character set modifier*, available since 5.14. But that has an effect broader than restricting just `\d`.  Search for `/a` in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).
Thus here I used `0-9` for precision and a small measure of efficiency, and without restricting `\s`, `\w` and POSIX character classes.

Comment: With `/a` modifier, `\d` matches only `[0-9]`, see: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Comment: @Toto  Thank you, that is what I was referring to by "_without modifiers_".  I didn't want to get into details since then `/aa` need be involved as well, while this was a side note.  But it's better to state it, thank you.

Comment: @Toto I did add this to text, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a function doing that kind of sorting some time ago.
It does numeric sorting using all numbers within a string.
I didn't care about performance, sorry. Hope it helps.

```
sub num_sort($$) {
  my ($a,$b)=@_;
  my @sa=reverse grep /./s, split /(\d+)/,$a;
  my @sb=reverse grep /./s, split /(\d+)/,$b;
  for (;; ) {
    last if !@sa || !@sb;
    my $ea=pop @sa;
    my $eb=pop @sb;
    my $rc= ($ea <=> $eb) || ($ea cmp $eb);
    if ($rc) {
      return $rc;
    }
  }
  return @sa <=> @sb;
}
```